# C++ 17: How to call a different constructor using if constexpr?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, if-constexpr

Say I have a class that takes a boolean in its constructor and depends on the value of the boolean, if calls different functions.

```
class MyClass {
    MyClass(bool is_second)
    {
        common_code();
        if (!is_second)
            first_constructor();
        else
            second_constructor();
    }
};
```

I am new to C++17 and I am wondering if it is possible to write this logic using template programming and `if constexpr`. The api is something like this:

```
MyClass<> obj_calls_first_const;
MyClass<is_second_tag> obj_calls_second_const;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Complying to your desired API:

```
struct is_second_tag { };

template <typename T = void>
struct MyClass
{
    MyClass()
    {
        if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, is_second_tag>)
        {
            second_constructor();
        }
        else 
        {
            first_constructor();
        }
    }
};
```

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dZ3wGPMEyha6aQWq)

Comment: Thanks. It works. If I have more than two branches (say is_third_tag, etc.). Can I use enums as the template variable?